# I need to post the co-ordinate populated from drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am able to populate the co-ordinates for each element I cant figure out how to play around with jquery $(this) or each to be able to post the co-ordinates of each list box. Some one point me to the right direction am a little lost here.

My HTML

```
 <div id = "container" >
        <ul>
            <li id="" class="ui-state-highlight items">First name</li>
            <li id="" class="ui-state-highlight items">Middle name</li>
            <li id="" class="ui-state-highlight items">Event name<div id ="posX"></div><div id ="posY"></div></li>
            <li id="" class="ui-state-highlight items">Logo<div id ="posX"></div><div id ="posY"></div></li>
            <li id="" class="ui-state-highlight items">Footer<div id ="posX"></div><div id ="posY"></div></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
```

My javascript

```
        $('.items').draggable({
            containment: '#container',
            cursor: 'move',
            drag: function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var xPos = offset.left;
                var yPos = offset.top;
                $(this).text('X : ' + xPos + ' y: ' + yPos);
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the position of all items during a single drag, then you have to select them manually, and process them:

```
$('.items').draggable({
    containment: '#container',
    cursor: 'move',
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        var childDivs = $(this).children('div');
        /*$(this).text( );
        $(this).text('X : ' + xPos + ' y: ' + yPos);*/
        $(childDivs[0]).text(xPos);
        $(childDivs[1]).text(yPos);

        // get position of other items
        $('.items').not(this).each(function () {
            var otherXPos = $(this).offset().left;
            var otherYPos = $(this).offset().top;
            var otherChildDivs = $(this).children('div');
            $(otherChildDivs[0]).text(xPos);
            $(otherChildDivs[1]).text(yPos);
            /*$(this).text( );
            $(this).text('X : ' + otherXPos + ' y: ' + otherYPos);*/
        });
    }
});
```

Note: your code has a lot of divs with the same `id` attribute. The `id` is meant to be unique, so these should be changed. Alternatively, you should use `name` instead.

Comment: That sounds like a solution but that will rise an issue since i am to create a foreach loop to populate the list items and assign an id from an array

Comment: @chapskev I assume you are referring to the ids thing? You don't need ids at all. I'll update my answer to do what I think it is you want.

Comment: that has been helpfull :) though i Still cant be able to post Individual Co-ordinate for each element

Comment: @chapskev If you want to post (submit) the data, then you need to put it in some sort of form field, not a div. E.g. a hidden input.